# D3 не хочет перерисовывать

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Друзья, помогите пожалуйста!

Сделал простенькую гистограмму - хочу чтобы она ресайзилась автоматом при изменении размеров окна браузера. Оформил примерно такой код:

```js
const data = new Array(20).fill(0).map(v => Math.random() * 50);

const redraw = () => {
  const width = d3.select('.bar-chart').node().clientWidth;

  console.log('FIRE_REDRAW', width);

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 50])
    .range([100, 300])
    .nice();

  const sections = d3
    .select('.bar-chart')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  sections
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .classed('cubic', true)
    .style('height', d => `${yScale(d)}px`)
    .style('width', d => `${width / data.length - 3}px`) 
}

redraw();
window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
```

Функция `redraw` вызывается, но увы график не перерисовывается. Что я упустил?

Код выложил в песочницу https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrdWXw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```js
    const data = new Array(20).fill(0).map(v => Math.random() * 50);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 50]).range([100, 300])
        .nice();

    const sections = d3
        .select('.bar-chart')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .classed('cubic', true);

    const redraw = () => {
  
        const width = d3.select('.bar-chart').node().clientWidth;

        sections
            .style('height', d => `${yScale(d)}px`)
            .style('width', d => `${width / data.length - 3}px`)
    }

    redraw();
    window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.cubic {
    background-color: #F00;    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-chart">
 
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/wNoZag)

Comment: отличное решение, спасибо!

Comment: @carcinogen75 пожалуйста, обращайтесь